# Получение данных из незаконченного скрипта PHP

Tags: php

у меня есть код.

```
echo '312321';
$get = [21312,321312];
sleep(2);
echo $get[0];
sleep(5);
echo 'sdsds';
```

Мне нужно чтобы данные выводились на сайт не через 7 секунд, а последовательно, т.е сначала вывелось 312321, потом через 2 секунды 213321, и потом через 5с. sdsds. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, на стороне php - никак. Нужно делать это на стороне фронта с помощью js.

Comment: Ну и для знакомства http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke